# ECDH between C# and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, webcrypto-api, ecdh

I'm building a web API and I need to implement ECDH to perform an end-to-end cryptography. At the server side I have a C# application and at the client side I have a Javascript application.

I'm able to exchange the keys, generate the private keys and encrypt the messages, but I'm having problems decrypting it.

I think the problem is in the exchange of the public keys. In javascript keys starts with a byte "4" and .NET keys starts with 8 bytes identifying the type and the size of the key, I need to change this bytes in order to import each key (Information that I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24255090/10297094)). Maybe this cause some inconsistencies.

At the client side I'm using the Web Cryptography API to handle with the ECDH. I'm implementing as follows.

Generating the keys

```
await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "ECDH",
            namedCurve: "P-256",
        },
        false,
        ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"]
    );
```

Exporting the public key like this:

```
await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
        "raw",
        publicKey
    );
```

Importing the external public key

```
await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        {
            name: "ECDH",
            namedCurve: "P-256",
        },
        false,
        ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"]
    )
```

And finally deriving the key

```
await window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
        {
            name: "ECDH",
            namedCurve: "P-256",
            public: publicKey,
        },
        privateKey,
        {
            name: "AES-CBC",
            length: 256,
        },
        false,
        ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    )
```

At the server side I'm implementing the same steps as follow.
Generating Public Key

```
private static ECDiffieHellmanCng ecdh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(256);

public static void GeneratePublicKey()
{
    ecdh.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
    ecdh.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
    publicKey = ecdh.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
}
```

Exporting public key. Note that I change the first bytes

```
public static byte[] GetPublicKey()
    {
        var auxKey = publicKey.Skip(7).ToArray();
        auxKey[0] = 4;

        return auxKey;
    }
```

Importing public key and deriving private key. Note that I change the first bytes

```
public static void GerarChavePrivada(byte[] bobPublicKey)
{
    byte[] aux = new byte[bobPublicKey.Length + 7];

    aux[0] = 0x45;
    aux[1] = 0x43;
    aux[2] = 0x4B;
    aux[3] = 0x31;
    aux[4] = 0x20;
    aux[5] = 0x00;
    aux[6] = 0x00;
    aux[7] = 0x00;

    for (int i = 1; i < bobPublicKey.Length; i++)
    {
        aux[7 + i] = bobPublicKey[i];
    }

    var importedKey = CngKey.Import(aux, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
    privateKey = ecdh.DeriveKeyMaterial(importedKey);
}
```

I belive the problem is about those keys. Any way these are the encrypt and decrypt codes:

Javascript

```
async function encrypt2(iv, key, data){
    var mensagemCriptografada;

    await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: "AES-CBC",
            iv: iv,
        },
        key,
        str2ab(data) //Data is a string and I'm converting using str2ab method.
    )

    .then(function(encrypted){
        mensagemCriptografada = encrypted;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });

    return mensagemCriptografada;
}

function str2ab (str) {
    var array = new Uint8Array(str.length);     
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        array[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return array.buffer
}
```

C#

```
string decMessage = "";

        using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aes.Key = privateKey;
            aes.IV = iv; //IV is the same used by the javascript code
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            var dec = aes.CreateDecryptor(privateKey, iv);

            var plain = dec.TransformFinalBlock(message, 0, message.Length);

            //I've tried every possible enconding.
            decMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plain); 
        }

        return decMessage;
```

I'm really don't have any idea how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Your C# code made possible the correct export of public key for javascript and import of public key for C# and @Paul answer gives the correct final shared key. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. After debugging more, I realised that the key generated by the C# with DeriveKeyMaterial is then hashed with SHA-256.

My solution is on the javascript to export the derivated key, hash it then import it as a new key.

```
cryptoApi().deriveKey(
  {
      name: "ECDH",
      namedCurve: "P-256", //can be "P-256", "P-384", or "P-521"
      public: ServerKey, //an ECDH public key from generateKey or importKey
  },
  ECkey.privateKey, //your ECDH private key from generateKey or importKey
  { //the key type you want to create based on the derived bits
      name: "AES-CBC", //can be any AES algorithm ("AES-CTR", "AES-CBC", "AES-CMAC", "AES-GCM", "AES-CFB", "AES-KW", "ECDH", "DH", or "HMAC")
      //the generateKey parameters for that type of algorithm
      length: 256, //can be  128, 192, or 256
  },
  true, //whether the derived key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
  ["encrypt", "decrypt"] //limited to the options in that algorithm's importKey
)
.then(function(AESKeyData){
  //returns the exported key data
  console.log(AESKeyData);

  cryptoApi().exportKey('raw',
    AESKeyData
  ).then(function (exportedAESKeyData) {
      cryptoApi().digest('SHA-256', exportedAESKeyData).then(function (HashedAESKeyValue) {
          console.log(HashedAESKeyValue);

          cryptoApi().importKey(
            'raw',
            HashedAESKeyValue,
            { //the key type you want to create based on the derived bits
                name: "AES-CBC", //can be any AES algorithm ("AES-CTR", "AES-CBC", "AES-CMAC", "AES-GCM", "AES-CFB", "AES-KW", "ECDH", "DH", or "HMAC")
                //the generateKey parameters for that type of algorithm
                length: 256, //can be  128, 192, or 256
            },
            false,
            ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
        ).then(function (TrueAESKey) {

            cryptoApi().decrypt(
               {
                   name: 'AES-CBC',
                   length: 256,
                   iv: base64ToArrayBuffer(IV)
               },
               TrueAESKey,
               base64ToArrayBuffer(EncryptedData)
               ).then(function (decrypted) {
                   console.log(buf2hex(decrypted));
               });
        })
      });
  });


})
```

Comment: Definitively saving my hours of trying to make javascript - c# ECDH through REST api.
Thank you @Paul!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [PKI.js](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js)? There you could find a complete implementation of all possible key encryption schemas for CMS Enveloped/Encrypted Data. Also there are [live examples](http://pkijs.org/#examples) and [here is](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/tree/master/examples) the source code for all the examples. Please notice there is [WiKi page](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/wiki/Working-with-CMS-EnvelopedData) regarding working with CMS EnvelopedData in PKI.js.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I didn't find any example of key exchange in the documentation and I don't think the problem is encrypting the data. Two javascript applications using the code above works perfectly as well as two .NET applications. The problem lies in this cross-plataform comunication.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way

Full exemple in [gist](https://gist.github.com/erycson/044f54dfbe1c92ae9638e32dc7105bdd)

```js
class Protector {
  ab2str(buffer) {
    return new TextDecoder().decode(buffer);
  }

  str2ab(text) {
    return new TextEncoder().encode(text);
  }

  generateIv() {
    return crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
  }

  /**
   * @see https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/web-crypto/derive-bits/ecdh.js
   */
  async generateKey() {
    this.key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
      { name: 'ECDH', namedCurve: 'P-256' },
      false,
      ['deriveBits']
    );
  }

  async encrypt(plaintext) {
    const counter = this.generateIv();
    const buffer = await crypto.subtle.decrypt({
      name: 'aes-ctr',
      counter: counter,
      length: 128
    }, this.importedKey, this.str2ab(plaintext));
    return { buffer, counter };
  }

  async decrypt(data) {
    const buffer = await crypto.subtle.decrypt({
      name: 'aes-ctr',
      counter: data.counter,
      length: 128
    }, this.importedKey, data.buffer);
    return this.ab2str(buffer);
  }

  getPublicKey() {
    return {publicKey: this.key.publicKey};
  }

  async setRemotePublicKey(key) {
    this.clientKey = key;
    
    this.sharedSecret = await window.crypto.subtle.deriveBits(
      { name: 'ECDH', namedCurve: 'P-256', public: this.clientKey.publicKey },
      this.key.privateKey,
      256
    );

    this.importedKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
      'raw',
      this.sharedSecret,
      'aes-ctr',
      false,
      ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
    );
  }
}
```

How to use:

```js
(async () => {
  // Generate Keys
  const pro1 = new Protector();
  await pro1.generateKey();
  const pub1 = pro1.getPublicKey();

  const pro2 = new Protector();
  await pro2.generateKey();
  const pub2 = pro2.getPublicKey();

  // Exchange Keys
  await pro1.setRemotePublicKey(pub2);
  await pro2.setRemotePublicKey(pub1);

  // Let`s Encrypt
  const crypted = await pro1.encrypt('Hello World');
  const descrypted = await pro2.decrypt(crypted);
})();
```