# ECDsaCng key generated longer than expected 32-bytes

Tags: c#, ecdsa

I was playing around with the ECDsaCng, and I realised that the key size doesn't seem to be correct. From the code below, the privateKey variable, for instance, was a 104-long byte array, whereas I didn't expect it to be larger than 32.

What am I doing wrong?

```
        ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng(256);
        dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
        dsa.GenerateKey(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);
        var privateKey = dsa.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
        var publicKey = dsa.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The private key `d` is a random integer in `[1, n - 1]`, where `n` is the order of the base point `G`. The public key is the curve point `(x, y) = d * G`, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm). For `NIST P-256` ([`secp256r1`](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf)) `d`, `x` and `y` are encoded to 32 bytes (the values cannot be larger).

MS stores both keys in a specific format described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_ecckey_blob). The format for the public key has an 8 bytes header, followed by the 32 bytes `x`-value and the 32 bytes `y`-value, so that the total length is 72 bytes. The format for the private key has a (different) 8-byte header, followed by the 32 byte `x`-value, the 32 byte `y`-value, and the 32 byte `d`-value, so that the total length is 104 bytes, in accordance with the value you found. A detailed description of the headers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24255090/9014097).