# what is the CngKeyBlobFormat of EccPrivateBlob generated by CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP521/P256/P384?

Tags: c#, cng, ecdh

```
CngKey key = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP521, null,
   new CngKeyCreationParameters { ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport });    
byte[] keyBlob= key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
```

the length of keyBlob is 206. what is its format? which bytes are the 32 bytes private key and 64 bytes public key?

at [Import a Public key from somewhere else to CngKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251336/import-a-public-key-from-somewhere-else-to-cngkey), the length is 4+4+64+32=104.

Comment: It is a byte[].  A key takes a string input and creates a class object.  The string initialize the class (like a seed to a random number generators).   The key strength from NSA is listed at following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size

Comment: i mean the CngKey Blob Format. which bytes are the 32 bytes private key in the 206 bytes.

Comment: As I said the string is a seed into a pseudo random generator whose output are the 32 byte array.  It is not reversible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary structure of the blobs is the same for all three curves:

```
<magic number, 4 bytes><modulus length in bytes, 4 bytes><x-value of public key><y-value of public key><private key>
```

In detail applies:

- secp256r1 / NIST P-256

  ```
  Private: 45434B32 20000000 <x-value of public key, 32 bytes><y-value of public key, 32 bytes><private key, 32 bytes>   total length: 104 bytes
  Public:  45434B31 20000000 <x-value of public key, 32 bytes><y-value of public key, 32 bytes>                          total length:  72 bytes
  ```
- secp384r1 / NIST P-384

  ```
  Private: 45434B34 30000000 <x-value of public key, 48 bytes><y-value of public key, 48 bytes><private key, 48 bytes>   total length: 152 bytes
  Public:  45434B33 30000000 <x-value of public key, 48 bytes><y-value of public key, 48 bytes>                          total length: 104 bytes
  ```
- secp521r1 / NIST P-521

  ```
  Private: 45434B36 42000000 <x-value of public key, 66 bytes><y-value of public key, 66 bytes><private key, 66 bytes>   total length: 206 bytes
  Public:  45434B35 42000000 <x-value of public key, 66 bytes><y-value of public key, 66 bytes>                          total length: 140 bytes
  ```

The private key and the `x`- and `y`-component of the public key are stored in big-endian format. All three components have the length of the modulus. The different lengths of the blobs are thus caused by the different modulus of the curves.

See also: [SECG, SEC2](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf), [key blob format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_ecckey_blob?redirectedfrom=MSDN), [magic numbers](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/Interop/Windows/BCrypt/Interop.Blobs.cs), [format of ECCPublicBlob and ECCPrivateBlob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24255090/9014097)

Comment: thank you very much! would you please help me with another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414020/how-to-use-bitcoin-pub-private-key-to-do-ecdh