# Java Bouncy Castle : Invalid point encoding 0x45

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I am loading a public key in `java` using `bouncy castle` library but always getting error `Invalid point encoding 0x45`.

The public key is generated at client side using C# CNG APIs.

Java method 1:

```
public PublicKey loadPublicKey(String encodedPublicKey)
            throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        
        byte[] keybytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedPublicKey);
        
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        
        ECNamedCurveParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("P-256");
        
        ECPublicKeySpec keySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(params.getCurve().decodePoint(keybytes), params);
        
        return new BCECPublicKey("ECDH", keySpec, BouncyCastleProvider.CONFIGURATION);

    }
```

Method 2

```
public PublicKey loadPublicKey(String pKey) throws Exception {
        byte[] keybytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(pKey);
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        ECParameterSpec params = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("P-256");
        ECPublicKeySpec pubKey = new ECPublicKeySpec(params.getCurve().decodePoint(keybytes), params);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");
        return kf.generatePublic(pubKey);
    }
```

Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid point encoding 0x45
    at org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECCurve.decodePoint(ECCurve.java:443)
```

Below method to create public key

```
public static (byte[] publicKey, byte[] privateKey) CreateKeyPair()
        {
            using (ECDiffieHellmanCng cng = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(
                // need to do this to be able to export private key
                CngKey.Create(
                    CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256,
                    null,
                    new CngKeyCreationParameters
                    { ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport })))
            {
                cng.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
                cng.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
                // export both private and public keys and return
                var pr = cng.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
                var pub = cng.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
                return (pub, pr);
            }
        }
```

Public Key generated `RUNLMSAAAAHddHI6TOEDG/Ka7naBbLQH0u/DSFfbKJI2w0WSoxrmFkwKm1tktz4wD0rqnwkZp8FwdHJ+8OVrTcpDMmxrwvS6`

The key which I am receiving at java is of `72 bytes`. But I think `bouncy castle java` supports `64 bytes` of key.

I was also looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251336/import-a-public-key-from-somewhere-else-to-cngkey#answer-24255090) but did not get any help

Comment: Why are you drawing more attention to this Q?  It looks like you already have a good answer.  If you need more / different information, you should comment or edit the question to say what you need ... or ask a new one.  (If you simply wanted to reward the Topaco's answer ... you should have used the "Reward existing answer" reason ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C# code exports the public key as a Base64 encoded `EccPublicBlob` whose format is described in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24255090/9014097) given in the question:
The first 4 bytes 0x45434B31 denote in little endian order a public ECDH key for curve P-256, the following 4 bytes are in little endian order the key length in bytes (0x20000000 = 32), the rest are the x and y coordinates of the EC point i.e. the public key, 32 bytes each.
It is striking that in the key you posted, the second 4 bytes are 0x20000001, but the x and y coordinates are 32 bytes each. Possibly there is a copy/paste error here. Anyway, with the posted C# code, I cannot reproduce a key that has a value other than 0x20000000 in the second 4 bytes.

Java/BC does not directly support importing an `EccPublicBlob` (which is MS proprietary), but it does support importing an uncompressed public key. This results when the x and y coordinates are concatenated and 0x04 is used as prefix. The import with Java/BC is then possible as follows:

```java
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.ECPoint;
import java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.ECNamedCurveTable;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.ECPointUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECNamedCurveParameterSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECNamedCurveSpec;
...
public static PublicKey getPubKeyFromCurve(byte[] uncompRawPubKey, String curveName) throws Exception {
      ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(curveName);
      ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec(spec.getName(), spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
      ECPoint point = ECPointUtil.decodePoint(params.getCurve(), uncompRawPubKey);
      ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(point, params);
      KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", new BouncyCastleProvider());
      ECPublicKey pubKey = (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
      return pubKey;
}
```

Test (assuming `EccPublicBlob` is Base64 encoded like the posted one):

```java
import java.util.Base64;
...
String publicKeyBlob = "RUNLMSAAAAAFzw4IGY4N8PKVt0MGF38SAKU5ixJhptVUdrWzuPhFDOcj/2k4SlGRN1RpRMbar9Iu7Uvcx7Vtm8Wa0HSzWJdE";
byte[] rawPublic = new byte[65];
rawPublic[0] = 0x04;
System.arraycopy(Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyBlob), 8, rawPublic, 1, 64);
PublicKey pub = getPubKeyFromCurve(rawPublic, "P-256");
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pub.getEncoded())); // MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEBc8OCBmODfDylbdDBhd/EgClOYsSYabVVHa1s7j4RQznI/9pOEpRkTdUaUTG2q/SLu1L3Me1bZvFmtB0s1iXRA==
```

The test imports the `EccPublicBlob` and exports it as a Base64 encoded DER key in X.509/SPKI format. This can be read with an ASN.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/, and thus be verified.

---

Note that C# also supports the export of other formats. However, this depends on the version. E.g. as of .NET Core 3.0 there is the method [`ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.exportsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=net-6.0) that exports the public key in X.509/SPKI format, DER encoded. This format and encoding can be imported directly into Java using `X509EncodedKeySpec` (even without BouncyCastle).
In other versions of C#, BouncyCastle for C# can be used for the export, which also supports the X.509/SPKI format.
Since you didn't post your .NET version, it's unclear what specific alternatives exist for you.

---

Keep in mind that an ECDH key for P-256 can also be created more simply with:

```java
ECDiffieHellmanCng cng = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256)
```

or cross-platform with

```java
ECDiffieHellman ecdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256)
```